# Version conflict between vi and vim

Tags: macvim, version

I installed some plugins which is supported above `vi` version 7.4. When i open files with `vi` command its will show the plugin not supported with version 7.3. After that i was opened with `vim` command its working. Then i check the version using vi command its showing version 7.3 , in vim version is 8.x. So i checked origin vi command using `which vim` , which returns /usr/bin/vi.Its the softlink of another version vim. So I want
    to remove old version of vim without remove installed plugins

OS:MAC

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use original vi program, just add following alias to your bashrc.

```
alias vi='vim -u NONE'
```

Comment: Vim is improved

Comment: It's there any way to remove old version